# Actionbar menu items not visible

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-menu

I want icons on action bar, but I am getting them in the menu options...
Here is my xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/share"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Share on Whatsapp"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/medication"
        android:title="My Medications"
        android:icon="@drawable/medication"
        app:showAsAction="always" /> 

    <item
        android:id="@+id/coc"
        android:title="Add Circle of care"
        android:icon="@drawable/add_icon"
        app:showAsAction="always" /> 

    <item
        android:id="@+id/report"
        android:title="Report"
        android:icon="@drawable/report"
        app:showAsAction="always" /> 
</menu>
```

and here is the java

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.dashboard, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        menu.toggle(true);
        return true;
    }

    if(id == R.id.coc){
        startActivity(new Intent(Dashboard.this,CircleOfCare.class));
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

What am I missing.. I am extending Activity.. If I extend ActionBarActivity, it says, use theme.appcompat or descendant even when I am using that theme only. Please help, thanx in advance

Comment: Did you try replacing `app:` with `android:`?

Comment: @Karim thanx, it worked.. I didn't know about this, Last time I used the same code, but I think i must have extended the ActionbarActivity

Comment: yes probably! Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't using ActionBarActivity then try using

```
android:showAsAction="always"
```

instead of

```
app:showAsAction="always"
```